# DbUnit NoSuchTableException with Spring, Hibernate, HSQSLB

Tags: hibernate, spring, junit, dbunit

I'm doing some volunteer development for the local school district. They use Spring and Hibernate for a basic CRUD application.  I was able to get some JUnit tests running against a development database, but would not like to try it against HSQLDB using DbUnit.

I'm getting a NoSuchTableException with DbUnit loading initial data from an XML file. I've read the other posts on StackOverflow regarding this, and they tend to recommend setting Hibernate property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create-drop.  I've done this and still get the exception. I'm wondering if there is something basic in the setup that I'm missing.

This is my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:spring-test-datasource.xml",
        "classpath:spring-test-dao.xml"
})
@Transactional
public class HibernateRitsAdminDaoTest {
    @Autowired protected RitsAdminDao ritsAdminDao;
    @Autowired protected DataSource dataSource;
    protected IDatabaseTester dbTester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        dbTester = new DataSourceDatabaseTester(dataSource);
        IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream("test/RitsAdminsTest.xml"));
        dbTester.setDataSet(dataSet);
        dbTester.onSetup();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        dbTester.onTearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() throws Exception {
        List<RitsAdmin> ritsAdmins = ritsAdminDao.getAll();
        assertTrue(ritsAdmins.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

This is my DbUnit data for to populate the table:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <tbl_sn_rits_admins profile_id="1"/>
    <tbl_sn_rits_admins profile_id="6"/>
    <tbl_sn_rits_admins profile_id="88"/>
</dataset>
```

This is the datasource definition in spring-test-datasource.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:schoolnet"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

And this spring-test-dao.xml that has the DAO and Hibernate properties defined:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>us/mn/k12/district/domain/RitsAdmin.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

And lastly, here is the Hibernate file for the table:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="us.mn.k12.district.domain">
    <class name="RitsAdmin" table="tbl_sn_rits_admins" schema="dbo" catalog="schoolnet">
        <id name="profileId" type="long">
            <column name="profile_id" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Note that I set the hibernate property hbm2dll.auto to "create-drop". This is what the other SO posts suggest. This should create the table during initialization, but I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: tbl_sn_rits_admins
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:288)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at org.dbunit.AbstractDatabaseTester.executeOperation(AbstractDatabaseTester.java:190)
    at org.dbunit.AbstractDatabaseTester.onSetup(AbstractDatabaseTester.java:103)
    at us.mn.k12.district.dao.HibernateRitsAdminDaoTest.setUp(HibernateRitsAdminDaoTest.java:41)
... keeps going...
```

Is there a simple configuration I'm missing?   Do the schema and catalog names in the Hibernate file have to somehow match up with the hsqldb URL?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did your unit test start the hibernate framework. Because it looks like you want to use Hibernate to create the tables. But this only works if your test "starts" hibernate first.

Comment: that's right, first see if your spring context is loaded correctly before searching a problem in hibernate/dbunit. Remove that dbunit code and tell us if your spring beans are autoriwred or not.

Comment: Thanks guys, I removed the dbunit code and pointed to a different datasource - a MSSQL database we use for development.  I'm able to run queries from JUnit against that database, so I think the datasource and DAO beans are loading correctly.  Thoughts on how to "start" Hibernate?  Right now the Hibernate DAO extends another Hibernate class that has the basic store, delete, getById, etc. That class uses HibernateTemplate. Otherwise, what would I look for to try and find where/if Hibernate is "started"? Thanks!

Comment: If it worked for a normal (not in memmory Database) but not for an in memmory database, than the problem could be that you use two different in memmory data bases, or the database is "closed" after the initialization.

Comment: Found out that DbUnit queries by <catalog>.<schema>.<table_name>, in my case querying against table schoolnet.dbo.tbl_sn_rits_admins.  I still get the NoSuchTableException if I set the table name to schoolnet.dbo.tbl_sn_rits_admins in the DbUnit flat XML file.  If I eliminate the schema and catalog properties from the Hibernate XML file, then DbUnit and HSQLDB run fine.  Right now I'm thinking of moving the catalog and schema properties out of the Hibernate XML file for the table and into the Spring XML file. Is it a common idiom to have separate test and production Spring XML files?